# How to handle shared assemblies in web application

Tags: web-applications, assemblies, manifest, shared

I have read I lot of articles about managing assemblies, version control systems and manifest files but still havn´t figured out the way to go.

I got a web application, WCF services and some assemblies which is shared between the web application and services. All is written in .Net/C#/ASP.Net (framwork 4) and I am using Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Source Safe (yes I am ashamed but it´s not my fault...).

We currently host the web application and its services but the plan is that a customer will be able to host the web application or just use the services.

I would really appreciate to get some hints, tips and tricks about how to manage assembly versions and create manifest files. The example I read about manifest files are all based on applications (not web applications). Are manifest files really used for web? Are there any tools for managing versions and web sites?